# jQuery height won't use transition when set to 100% or auto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

JS FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/t2eynytg/1/

Essentially, I want a readmore button that reveals an entire long paragraph (which is normally cut to 3-4 lines). It "grows" with a transition when the desired height is set in pixels, but it just "appears" when set to auto or 100%. Obviously I want this to work for all cases, so it can't be in pixels or ems.

How do I fix?

jQuery

```
$('.first-link').click(function(){
    $('.first-pg').css({'height' : '100%'})
});
```

HTML

```
<p class="first-pg">
 This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. 
</p>
<a class="first-link" href="#">Read More</a>
```

CSS

```
p {
  height:3em;
  border:1px solid green;
  overflow:hidden;
  -webkit-transition: height .8s;
    -moz-transition: height .8s;
    transition: height .8s;
}
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877552/how-do-i-animate-a-specific-height-to-100-in-jquery

Comment: Your percentage-based height doesn't have a parent with a set height, therefore it does nothing. For example, change your height to 5%. Now to 50%. Now to 100%. It will behave the same in any case because it's simply **defaulting back to `height: auto;`**.  

Because this transition isn't animatable, in your case, you can't use this. As the comment above suggests, a work-around would be to set the height to auto, capture the height in pixels, and animate to that height instead. This calculation happens without user seeing it, therefore the animation appears smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Transition only works with hard values because it needs them to calculate start/finish values for the timing. So things like transitioning between `display: none;` and `display: block;` don't work (there is no quantitative value to scale from/to).

`Height: auto;` is not a hard value so you can't animate to/from it. What you can do is check what the value of height: auto *would be* using `scrollHeight` and then use that in your animation.

So for example:

`'height' : $('.first-pg')[0].scrollHeight`

Below is a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/oxn357az/

And further reading:

https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/

```js
/* Desired Effect */
var $firstPara = $('.first-pg');
$firstPara.prop({
 'original-height' :  $firstPara.height(),
  'open' : false
});
  
var $secondPara = $('.second-pg');
$secondPara.prop({
 'original-height' :  $secondPara.height(),
  'open' : false
});


$('.first-link').click(function(){
 if(!$firstPara.prop('open')){
    $firstPara.animate({
    'height' : $firstPara[0].scrollHeight
    })
    $firstPara.prop('open', true);
  }
  else{
    $firstPara.animate({
    'height' : $firstPara.prop('original-height')
    })
    $firstPara.prop('open', false);
  }
});

$('.second-link').click(function(){
 if(!$secondPara.prop('open')){
    $secondPara.animate({
    'height' : $secondPara[0].scrollHeight
    })
    $secondPara.prop('open', true);
  }
  else{
    $secondPara.animate({
    'height' : $firstPara.prop('original-height')
    })
    $secondPara.prop('open', false);
  }
});
```

```css
p {
  height:3em;
  border:1px solid green;
  overflow:hidden;
  -webkit-transition: height 5.8s;
 -moz-transition: height 5.8s;
 transition: height .8s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Desired Effect</h1>
<p class="first-pg">
 This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. 
</p>
<a class="first-link" href="#">Read More</a>

<h1>Issue</h1>
<p class="second-pg">
 This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. This is a long type test. 
</p>
<a class="second-link" href="#">Read More</a>
```